# Half of union subquery returning null

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to break my money column up into two columns (type a and b)

```
select case when t.type = 'a' then t.amount end,  
       case when t.type = 'b' then t.amount end, 
       t.accountNumber
    from (
    select 
    sum(t1.money) as amount,
    'a' as type,
    t1.accountNumber as accountNumber
    from table1 t1
    group by t1.accountNumber
    union
    select 
    sum(t2.money) as amount,
    'b' as type,
    t2.accountNumber as accountNumber
    group by t2.accountNumber
    from table2 t2  
    )t;
```

However, right now type b is returning a bunch of 'null' values. It seems to depend solely on which table comes before the union. For example, if i put type b where type a is then I would see the type b values and the type a values would be null. How can I see both values?

(First time posting so I'd also appreciate pointers on how I could ask questions better) Thanks! :)

Comment: _side note_: `group by` ___always___ goes after `from`. Also, `sum` returns `null` when all values in the group are `null`. You can use `coalesce` to work this thing out.

Comment: Woops, yeah that group by should be after. I've never used coalesce before as I'm new to sql, I'll give it a look, thanks!

Comment: I believe you're approach will yield multiple rows per account Number.  Did you want type A and B to be on the same line for the same account?

Comment: Yes! I was actually beginning to think about that. I think my type b column is returning 'null' because of this.

Comment: At least the question has developed to: How can I get type A and B on the same line? I've been playing with the group by's and case statements without much success.

Comment: Are you having all of the account numbers in both tables (or in at least one of them)? Did you try some `JOIN` instead of the `UNION` (which would require to adjust the outer query, of course)? Roughly how many grouped rows do you have to handle for each of the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments I think that the query below might be what you want, it would give you an output like:

```
sum_a   sum_b   accountNumber
100,00  NULL    1            -- account 1 is in table1
200,00  300,00  2            -- account 2 is in both tables
NULL    300,00  3            -- account 3 is in table2
```

```
select 
    max(case when t.type = 'a' then t.amount end) sum_a,  
    max(case when t.type = 'b' then t.amount end) sum_b, 
    t.accountNumber
from (
    select 
       sum(t1.money) as amount,
       'a' as type,
       t1.accountNumber as accountNumber
    from table1 t1
    group by t1.accountNumber
    union all
    select 
       sum(t2.money) as amount,
       'b' as type,
       t2.accountNumber as accountNumber
    from table2 t2  
    group by t2.accountNumber
)t
group by t.accountNumber;
```

Alternatively you could use a `full outer join` to achieve the same result:

```
select 
    sum(a.money) sum_a, 
    sum(b.money) sum_b, 
    coalesce(a.accountNumber, b.accountnumber) AccountNumber
from table1 a full outer join table2 b on a.accountnumber = b.accountnumber
group by coalesce(a.accountnumber, b.accountnumber);
```

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I'm unfamiliar with the max function, so I'll go investigate what's actually happening here. Thanks!

Comment: @Jataca Try removing the max and group by and you'll get an idea why it's used here. (It's to flatten rows)